# Why is this page layout breaking when an anchor link is used

Tags: css

My page http://dl.dropbox.com/u/49912546/anchor_link_test.htm displays differently when an anchor is used too http://dl.dropbox.com/u/49912546/anchor_link_test.htm#vanquish-s - content below an image is moved up slightly

This happens consistently across browsers, so there must be something in the spec that means this is the correct behaviour... but what? It only happens when an image is loaded (if the src is invalid the bug doesn't happen).

*edit
By the way, I found a workaround already http://dl.dropbox.com/u/49912546/anchor_link_test_solved.htm#vanquish-s, so I'm not looking for  bug fix - I just want to know why all browsers have CSS implementations that cause this behaviour.

Comment: Maybe you should post your workaround, in case someone else has the same issue and doesn't know how to solve it.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`half content` appears to shift upwards because the `.panel` 
its contained within is set to `overflow:hidden` & has content that is being clipped as a result.

When the browser attempts to identify the element in the named anchor it sees thats its within a container that can clip its content & so scrolls that element to the top to ensure its visible.

For example if you were to add any elements within `contentInner` but above the named `h3`, then they would not be visible on the page when the named anchor was used as `half content`  is scrolled such that `h3` is at the top. (The same result  as if `overflow:scroll` were applied; the named anchor causes the scrollbar to position itself in line with the top of the named element)

Comment: After reading this about 5 times I finally get it, and yes, I see why the browser would want to make sure the element is visible. But couldn't the browser first check if the linked-to element is overflowing before doing this kind of hoisting? 

Also, in cases where the element is hidden using other means, e.g. position absolute http://dl.dropbox.com/u/49912546/anchor_link_test_counterexample.htm#vanquish-s, the browser makes no attempt to drag the content in to view. So why don't browsers accept that overflow:hidden means hidden, and jump to the closest sensible visible place?

Comment: I agree its a clunky way of doing things, there is a discussion of this behaviour here; http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/appendix/equalheightproblems

Answer (score 1):

After searching for a workaround, I found that using `overflow: clip;` instead of `hidden` fixed the half content issue.

Doing this will prevent all scrolling, thus preventing the browser to scroll the clipped content.

> Similar to hidden, the content is clipped to the element's padding box. The difference between clip and hidden is that the clip keyword also forbids all scrolling, including programmatic scrolling. The box is not a scroll container, and does not start a new formatting context. If you wish to start a new formatting context, you can use display: flow-root to do so. - MDN docs

Answer (score 0):

In my case removing overflow:hidden worked

```
#maincontent {
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    clear:both;
}
```