# HTML anchor links break site / don't work properly?

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, anchor-scroll

Working on personal site, found that whenever ANY of the HTML anchors is clicked, it completely breaks the site OR simply doesn't link to the appropriate location on the webpage. Typically occurs on Firefox, but site works fine on Edge and Chrome.

The live version of the site is here: http://smithchrisgraphics.com/

The issue is most obvious when using Firefox; when I tested my site using Edge, I didn't have any problems. I tried reducing the HTML and CSS down to see if I could pinpoint the issue, and I still don't know what is causing the bug. Any help pinpointing what's wrong would help. I removed all external js files.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
    /* CSS Document */
    html
    {
    overflow-x:hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }

    body
    {
    min-height: 500vh;
    max-width: 100vw;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: -13px;
    z-index: -3;
    /*outline: 1px solid red;*/
    }

    .displaySection
    {
    position: relative;
    top: 100vh;
    left: 0;
    
    width: 100%;    
    background-color: red;
    padding: 20px 0 20px;
    margin: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: visible;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    a
    {
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    ul
    {
    list-style: none;
    }

    hr
    {
    margin: 50px 10px 10px 10px;
    }

    #wrapper
    {   
    width:100vw;    
    }

    #NameDrop
    {
    position: relative;
    top: 50vh;
    transform: translateY(-60%);
    
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    z-index: 5;
        
    }

    #NameDrop ul 
    {
    text-decoration-line: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 40%;
    }

    #NameDrop ul li
    {
    text-decoration-line: none;
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    
    }

    #NameDrop li a
    {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding:10px 20px;
    left: -20px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration-line: none;
    font-size: 14pt;
    border-radius: 30px;
    
    opacity: 1;
    
    /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-name: SlowFade;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;

    /* Standard syntax */
    animation-name: SlowFade; 
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-delay: 0.7s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-direction: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    -o-transition: 0.3s;
    -mozilla-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.3s;
    
    }

    #NameDrop li a:hover
    {
    background-color:rgba(151,0,2,1.00);
    color: white;
    text-decoration-line: none;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- External CSS Files -->
    <link href="css/home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    
    <!-- Need script for anchors due to HTML5 Bug on browsers -->
    <script>
    function snapToAnchor(anchor)
    {
        document.getElementById(anchor).scrollIntoView(true);
    }
    </script>
    
     </head>


    <body> 
    
    <div id="NameDrop"> 
    
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#link01">About</a></li>
        <li><a onclick="snapToAnchor('link02')">Design</a></li>
        <li><a onclick="snapToAnchor('link03')">Experience</a></li>
        <li><a href="#link04">Education</a></li>
        <li><a onclick="snapToAnchor('link05')">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Each section should take up a minimum of at least 1 full screen -->
    <div id="link01" class="displaySection">
    
    </div>
    
    <div id="link02" class="displaySection">
    
    </div>
    
    <div id="link03" class="displaySection">
    
    </div>
    
    <div id="link04" class="displaySection">
    
    </div>
    
    <div id="link05" class="displaySection">
    
    </div>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

If there is ANY extra details I can provide to help, or you have any clue what could be causing this, please let me know!

Comment: Why does HTML have a negative z-index? --- Firefox smoothly scrolls if you remove the overflow hiddens.

Comment: *it completely breaks the site* <-- What does that mean?

Comment: From basic digging your issue seems to stem from your usage of `.scrollIntoView(true);` It works for some elements on firefox, but not your `<section>` elements. If I add an id to one of the children of your `<section>` elements and target that, it works just fine. Now the question becomes why.

Comment: @evolutionxbox TBH For some ungodly reason I suspected the z-index was behind the issue; it doesn't seem to be, after toying with it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus When a link is clicked, a part of the site appears to be removed or becomes unaccessible without reloading the page. This entire issue is new, as the site had been online for over a year without this issue and had working anchors.

Comment: @David for some reason when I tried that, I opened up Edge browser to see if it would work there too - it stopped working in Edge. I'm so lost why it breaks in one browser, I thought anchor tags and the `scrollIntoView()` functions were supposed to work with every browser. Will begin trying to make a new site or something at the rate it's going...

Comment: The z-index isn’t even being applied. I was confused why it was there

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the `overflow: hidden` style on the body tag, when removed the anchor links works properly.

This can be related to this question [Why is this page layout breaking when an anchor link is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240967/why-is-this-page-layout-breaking-when-an-anchor-link-is-used)

> `half content` appears to shift upwards because the .panel its contained
> within is set to overflow:hidden & has content that is being clipped
> as a result.